# Unable to create a project using laravel framework on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, composer-php

Laravel (ubuntu):  after installation of composer in the directory www/laravel i tried to create the project  with the command (composer create-project laravel/laravel project1 --prefer-dist) but an error is popped

Error : No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found

Comment: I think you either need to use `./composer` or `composer.phar` if you "installed" it in that directory.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to install composer is by installing it globally:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now you can run:

```
$ composer
```

---

Another way is to install it locally, this is not recommended. That would mean only executing

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then, you should use:

```
$ ./composer.phar
# or
$ php composer.phar
```

Answer (score 1):

Your composer is not accessible globally or not installed properly.

Use below command to install it globally so that you can run composer command everywhere.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Notice the `--filename=composer` switch in the command it renames composer.phar to composer so that you can run `$ composer` instead of `$ composer.phar`

Complete guide about installing Laravel on Ubuntu can be found here:
http://scriptbaker.com/install-laravel-on-ubuntu/